# Connection issues implementing Django Custom Storage backend with Box Cloud Storage API

Tags: django, box

I am working on a legacy Django application that has a lot of third party dependencies, one of which is the storage backend for file uploads.  I was recently tasked with replacing our legacy third party cloud storage vendor with a newer cloud storage vendor (Box).

The cloud storage is implemented as a custom storage backend and used as the "storage" parameter in FileFields in models throughout the app.  I'm basically trying to figure out what exactly happens in storage if you have a FileField in a model and you create a ModelForm based on that model, then you call "save" on the form.

It seems that a lot of stuff is going on and some of it is causing connection problems with the cloud storage API.

I tried reading the Django source to follow it and got all the way down to where the model is deciding if it should do an update (by doing an "exists" check in storage) or an insert.

Once it decides to do an insert, I noticed a call to my cloud storage backend occurs to upload the file (presumably non blocking?) as the insert sql is being generated.

Somewhere in here, connections to the cloud storage begin to hang and become unresponsive. At least, all I see in logs is

> INFO requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): upload.box.com"

and no further info or response.

Unlike the previous cloud storage, the new one issues JWT's per session instead of having a static auth token that you simply pass every time. If I do not use Django's ModelForm with its magical "save" method, but call methods directly on the models with the FileFields, I do not encounter the connection problem - I get responses just fine from the cloud storage API.

So, I'm thinking there must be some kind of concurrency issue when calling "save" on a form that affects a model with a FileField??  I'm a little stumped.  The code is involved, so it is hard to copy here, but basically it comes down to:

```
class CustomStorage:
    def __init__(self):
        set up storage API client, 
        authenticate client instance, etc

    def _save(self, name):
        call storage API methods to upload file
        ** includes a retry loop with file renaming
           algorithm to avoid name conflicts, as 
           cloud API does not allow duplicate file 
           names

    def exists(self, name):
        call storage API methods to determine if file name conflict exists

    def _open(self, name):
        call storage API methods to download file


custom_storage = CustomStorage()


class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(maxlength=255)
    file_ref = FPFileField(upload_to="uploads", storage=custom_storage) #because we also have a dependency on FilePicker, now called FileStack


class ExampleModelForm(ModelForm):
    file_ref = CustomFilePickerField()
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ('name', 'file_obj')


form = ExampleModelForm()
model = form.save() # --> connection problem with 
                    # cloud storage API starts here
                    # if I were to call ExampleModel.objects.create(...),
                    # the storage upload process would work fine
```

Is there some gotcha I'm not aware of that Django experts would know about implementing custom storage backends for Django based on cloud storage APIs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I added some whitespace and formatting to your post to improve the reading experience. To further along your problem, please mention any `clean()` method on the model. This the main difference between `objects.create()` and `form.save()`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help and further question, Melvyn.  I don't see any explicit overloads of `clean()` in our models.

Comment: Any chance you can inject a [timeout](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/stable/user/quickstart/#timeouts) to get a sense of where this was invoked from?

Comment: @Melvyn, it seems like the stack of calls ends off somewhere inside the django models sql compiler - not sure how this connects with the FileField.
`django/db/models/sql/query/get_compiler().execute_sql()`
inside execute_sql: 
`with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():`
     --> this is where the storage API call gets kicked off, as soon as the above iteration begins

Comment: If you're able, can you edit your post with that trace including line numbers. I don't know what self is here and there's several as_sql() methods. It may be a [custom lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-lookups/), which would make the most sense.

Comment: I'm checking with Box support, as I've pretty much determined the only difference between creating a model instance directly and calling form.save on a modelform based on that model is that the modelform.save() involves an update vs insert check that calls "exists" in the storage API before committing a change.  I think this extra call is where the session seems to differ.  In my custom storage based on the Box API I do a test call for a file ID to check if the file exists in storage and catch the ensuing exception, and return false, if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: That's a very good analysis and model_instance.save() should yield the same problem. manager.create() has `force_insert` set to True allowing it to skip the exists check to determine the action. If you can write this up as answer, I think it will benefit others greatly as this is one of those "hidden gems".

Comment: Hm, I was excited about this option and tried it, but I still got the hung connection in the end.  I tried `model = modelform.save(commit=False)` and then `model.save(force_insert=True)`, but it resulted in pretty much the same hung connection right after the multipart/form-data post from my app to Box.  Seems like the final expected response from the Box API should be a JSON summary of the uploaded file and that's what's hanging in the modelform.save() version.

Comment: Went down another rabbit hole and discovered that the issue could actually be FilePicker/FileStack and the Requests library, not Django.  Apparently the temporary file upload we are obtaining from the FPFileField is sometimes a File-like object in read mode and sometimes a StringIO object with some missing methods/attributes that would normally be on a file-like object.  The type hierarchy either looks like FPFile > Django base File > Python File or FPFile > Django base file > StringIO object.  The StringIO ones are the ones that are failing.

Comment: It seems to hang way down in httplib where it tries to chunk the StringIO bytes into 8192-byte parts in a loop.   It hangs up on the final step of the loop.  This seems related to a PR/issue made in Requests in 2015 (https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2872) , but sadly, the Box Python SDK has a dep for Requests v 2.4.3 which is from 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was our usage of a deprecated version of a FilePicker field for the uploaded document model field, combined with an old bug in a stale version of Requests.  Occasionally, this field would return a Django file instance wrapped around a cStringIO.StringIO object instead of a vanilla file object.  This ended up running into a bug in the Requests library which caused stalled responses when chunking for a multi-part POST when the payload is a StringIO instance.  Because upgrading is not an option, I solved the issue by detecting if the the underlying Django FileField File is not a file object and re-wrapping it in a ContentFile instance and seek-ing to 0, in order to play nice with the older version of Requests.  If anyone knows of a better alternative, by all means, please let me know.